# Slack API slash command stripping out hyperlinks

Tags: slack, slack-api

I have created a slash command in Slack and am successfully receiving the relevant payload from that slash command. However, when the user creates a message that contains an embedded hyperlink, that link is being stripped out of the message and isn't included in the message payload.

For example:

This message contains a [link](https://www.google.com)

...gets converted to:

This message contains a link

Oddly, the link is successfully passed through as part of the payload if the user types a naked URL in their message, but it does not work if they create a link using the 'link' button in the Slack UI.

As per the [docs](https://api.slack.com/interactivity/slash-commands#creating_commands), I have enabled the option "Escape channels, users, and links sent to your app" but this doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Can anyone help? How can ensure embedded hyperlinks aren't stripped out of the message payload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slack unfortunately haven't spent much time on slash commands since launch, and one of the things they don't support are links, as they were only added recently to the client's rich text editor.

Previously there was no way to create a link to a non-slack resource without pasting the full URL, so the slash command isn't sent it.

Your best option, if you are trying to do something with a link, would be to respond ephemerally to the user stating this and asking them to send the full URL via the slash command instead.

Comment: I thought as much. Thanks for answering @mattietk